# Как заносить файл в переменную?

Tags: pascal

Как заносить файл в переменную? В Turbo Pascal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Нетипизированные файлы: `var myFile : file;`
2. Типизированные:  `var integerFile : file of integer; var strFile : file of string[100];`
3. Текстовые: `var textFile : text;`

Чтобы привязать файл к переменной:

```
assign(textFile, 'path/to/file/filename.txt');
```

Открыть на чтение:

```
reset(textFile);
```

Открыть на запись:

```
rewrite(textFile);
```

Открыть на запись в конец файла:

```
append(textFile);
```

Закрыть файл:

```
close(textFile);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Какой тип файла?
2. В одну переменную не занесешь, лучше в массив, считывать построчно файл все равно придется.

-

```
Assign(f2, ‘file2.txt’);
Rewrite(f2); {открываем второй файл для записи}

While not eof(f2) do
Begin
    Readln(f2,s);{считываем очередную строку из первого файла}
    WriteLn(s);
End;
```

Ну вроде как-то так. Это если просто считывать и выводить сразу.

Comment: нужно только описать переменную, без каких либо действий, то есть какой тип у файловой переменной

Comment: >var f2:file;
>var f2:file of integer;
и т.д. и т.п.